# 10.11: Good Samaritan message not showing on Filevault2 unlock screen

Tags: macos, startup, filevault, encryption, unlock

You can set up a lock Message under `System Preferences => Security & Privacy => General => Set Lock Message.`
This Message is stored in NVRAM. Under 10.9 Mavericks it was not only shown on Login/Fast User switch window but also on the FileVault2 Login Screen after a cold boot which makes a whole lot of sense. On 10.11 El Capitan this feature is gone. The Message is only shown on the normal Login/Fast User switch window after the machine has already been unlocked.
Is there a way to revert 10.9 behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it myself by updating my user picture under `System Preferences => Users & Groups` *after* setting the Lock Message. Now it appears again on FileVault2 Screen

Comment: Awesome! Please mark this as answered